# Is there a penalty for escaping from fights?

Tags: neo-the-world-ends-with-you

In the original TWEWY, escaping from battles repeatedly would lower the Sync Rate between Neku and his partner. Sync Rate seems to be absent from NEO: TWEWY, but you still have the option to escape from fights after running out of hp.

Since sync rate was removed, is there any penalty for escaping from fights in NEO: TWEWY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, a portion of your Groove at the end of a battle carries over to the next battle. If you escape from a battle, this carry-over is lost.

Also, if you had a rare light blue noise in the chain, it'll despawn if you escape, although it still has a chance to respawn each time you leave the area and come back.

As far as I can tell, those are the only 2 drawbacks of running away.